# AutoHotkey: how to receive object-based array from WinGet()?

Tags: autohotkey

What I really want is passing the result from `WinGet` to another function. pseudo-array seems not possible being passed. But always stuffing an object-based array with values in a pseudo-array is not efficient.

`WinGet, OutputVar , SubCommand, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText`

Comment: the fastest way might be declaring all the variables inside the function as global, you do that by simply putting `global` as the first line inside the function. That way you will be able to access all the variables that are declared in the main script, including all the pseudo array members.

Comment: "always stuffing an object-based array with values in a pseudo-array is not efficient."  In what way is it not efficient? Just write a function that will do it and use it. This kind of "object mapping" is done all the time, it will have as much effect on the efficiency of your program as the effect you're having on Earth when you stand on it.

Comment: Another option is to use a label-defined subroutine instead of a function. Then you won't have to pass anything as it will have access to all non-local variables script-wide. You could use `GoSub` to "call" it instead of a function.